# Vscode debugger hits a breakpoint on page reload

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm debugging a react application using VS Code debugger for Edge (The newer Chromium edition, I used to use Chrome, AFAIR there was the same problem). When I reload a page, the "paused in debugger" label appears a couple of times, then disappears. It doesn't bother me too much, but the problem is it always opens *Sources* panel and because  of that on every reload I have to open *Console* manually which is very annoying.

I'm absolutely sure I have no breakpoints on, the *Breakpoints* panel in Edge is empty, the *Breakpoints* panel in VS Code only contains my breakpoints and the problem persists if I disable all of them. I also have *Uncaught exceptions* breakpoint turned on, but disabling it doesn't help. Sources panel opens some React internal file, namely `injectGlobalHook.js`. Also sometimes after reloading a page I open VS Code to find that it opened a tab with `react-dom.development.js` for some reason. Is it supposed to work like this? And is it possible to make *Console* tab open on reload, because it's impossible to work like this

Comment: Have you tried any other application to debug?

Comment: @MaulikSakhida, no, I actually don't know any remote debug tools apart from vs code extensions, what can I try?

Comment: I mean try to debug some another react web application with VSCode and see if you find same issue or not

Comment: @MaulikSakhida, ah, I see, ok I'll try that

Comment: @MaulikSakhida, oh, no, it actually does happen on the empty project as well. I just didn't set any breakpoints, if I don't set anything, then it works fine, but as soon as I set at least one breakpoint, the issue appears and doesn't go away

Comment: There are lots of place in chrome where it hits the breakpoints. I would suggest if you can go through below link

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#:~:text=Right%2Dclick%20an%20entry%20to,breakpoints%2C%20or%20remove%20all%20breakpoints.

Comment: Or if you can attach Screenshots where you get hit, that might help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223866/discussion-between-maulik-sakhida-and-alex-chashin).